Why do not multiple Composable functions overlap in a LazyItemScope(an item within LazyColumn or LazyRow)
In common compose layout, multiple children may overlap just like they are in a Box(like flutter Stack). When I try to put multiple children into a LazyList(LazyColumn or LazyRow)' s item block, they are positioned in order and are not overlapped. What special thing does LazyItemScope do? Does the item put all its children into a Column or a Row?

@Composable
fun Container1() { // A and B are overlapped
    Text("A")
    Text("B")
}

@Composable
fun Container2() {
    LazyColumn { // or LazyRow
        item { // A and B are not overlapped, their orientation is same as LazyList' s orientation
            Text("A")
            Text("B")
        }
        items {}
        item {}
    }
}


Layout composables do not display any UI themselves, instead they just lay out their children according to a given layout strategy.
A Box is just a simple container without any special layout logic so multiple children stack. A Column (and the same also applies to LazyColumn), however, lays out its children in a column, hence the name. That is, each child is placed below the previous one so the result is, well, a column of children composables.
By the same token a Row (and also a LazyRow) lays out its children in a row, that is, each child is placed to the right of the previous child.
That's actually their main purpose. When Column and Row wouldn't have this behavior they were useless because you would always use a Box instead.
This is even more true for the Lazy variants. The only reason to use a LazyColumn instead of a Column is to prevent items from being composed that are currently scrolled off-screen (to improve performance). When all items were placed above each other (stacked), the entire Lazy logic would be superfluous because everything would be displayed all the time.

But I want to ask about contents in an item, instead of items in an LazyColumn. Of course items are in the column.
